# QML debugging in visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, visual-studio-2012

[image]I use visual studio to build and run my Qt based application. I can keep breakpoints in my c++  files but QML no way I am able to keep breakpoints. The way I debug QML is keeping console.log() statment.

From internet I saw extention "QT VS tools" but dont know how to use it.

1. DO I need to create pro file to do debug even if I can build QT based project
2. I am using VC2019, do I need to upgrade Vs

Please provide some info

Answer (score 0):

1. No
2. No (but I recommend to do it)

You can follow [official guide](https://doc.qt.io/qtvstools/qtvstools-debugging-qt-quick.html) to configure debugging.

Comment: Official guide is not helpful in this case as you can see the "Qt Project Settings" menu item is disabled and its not possible to enable QML debugging

Comment: @RasheduzzamanSourov so what type of project do you use? For visual studio solutions (.sln) and qt projects (.pro) it works.

Comment: Its a cmake project and we are using ninja build tool

Comment: If you need full IDE features you should use native solutions. You can generate them from CMake and slightly patch (as a generation step) vcxprj files to tell to visul studio that it's a Qt libraries.